# How to print, with awk, duplicated fields in a column that have a specific amount of duplication

Tags: awk, text, columnsorting

Data:

| id | name | city | language | area_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Juan | Cali | ES | 44 |
| 01 | José | Cali | ES | 44 |
| 01 | Pedro | Cali | ES | 44 |
| 02 | Albert | Edinburgh |  | 19 |
| 02 | Mark |  | En | 19 |
| 03 | Raisa | Hellsinki | FI | 22 |
| 03 | Lisa | Hellsinki |  |  |
| 04 | Gian | Roma | IT | 33 |
| 05 | Loris | Sicilia |  |  |
| 05 | Vera | Sicilia |  | 31 |

The file containing this data is in next format:

```
01;Juan;Cali;ES;44
01;José;Cali;ES;44
01;Pedro;Cali;ES;44
02;Albert;Edinburgh;;19
02;Mark;;En;19
03;Raisa;Hellsinki;FI;22
03;Lisa;Hellsinki;;
04;Gian;Roma;IT;33
05;Loris;Sicilia;;
05;Vera;Sicilia;;31
```

In this data, rows with id = 02, 03, 05 have this very same field duplicated twice, so no matter what the rest of the data says, I need to be able to select only those rows that have the field id duplicated twice, so the expected result would be:

```
02;Albert;Edinburgh;;19
02;Mark;;En;19
03;Raisa;Hellsinki;FI;22
03;Lisa|Hellsinki;;
05;Loris;Sicilia;;
05;Vera;Sicilia;;31
```

So far I have only found the way to select rows duplicated any amount of times, which code is:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' 'a[$1]++{print $0}' data.file
```

But I haven't been able to figure out the way to obtain only those lines with the id duplicated twice...

**Update**: like U2, I still haven't found what I'm looking for, but I have a new awk command that I think is closer:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{a[$1]++; if (a[$1] == 2) {print $0}}' data.file
```

It correctly counts out the row with id 04, but includes rows with id 01 which is not exactly two times repeated but three...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2 passes:

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} cnt[$1]==2' file file
02;Albert;Edinburgh;;19
02;Mark;;En;19
03;Raisa;Hellsinki;FI;22
03;Lisa;Hellsinki;;
05;Loris;Sicilia;;
05;Vera;Sicilia;;31
```

or in 1 pass if your input is grouped by the first field as shown in your example (you can always `sort` it if not):

```
$ awk -F';' '
    $1 != prev { if (cnt == 2) print buf; prev=$1; buf=$0; cnt=1; next }
    { buf=buf ORS $0; cnt++ }
    END { if (cnt == 2) print buf }
' file
02;Albert;Edinburgh;;19
02;Mark;;En;19
03;Raisa;Hellsinki;FI;22
03;Lisa;Hellsinki;;
05;Loris;Sicilia;;
05;Vera;Sicilia;;31
```

Answer (score 0):

By and large, it's quicker to `sort` post-filtered rows. Here's a single-pass `awk-based` solution with no pre-`sort`ing or post-`sort`ing needed -

```
— output would be based on original input row order, 
  so presorted input means presorted output

- downside of this approach is needing 2 arrays.
```

|

```
 {m,g}awk -F';.+$' '{

        sub("$", NR "=", ____[$((_____[NR] = $-_)^_)]) 
 } END {
         FS = OFS = ORS (___=_="")
         $-_=_
     for (__ in ____) {
         if ((_=____[__]) ~"^[0-9]+=[0-9]+=$") {
                     $+_=_____[+_]
           sub("^[0-9]+[=]",___,_)
                     $+_=_____[+_]
     } }
     print $((__=(_=FS)"+")*gsub((_)__,_)*sub("^"__,___)) }'
```

|

```
02;Albert;Edinburgh;;19
02;Mark;;En;19
03;Raisa;Hellsinki;FI;22
03;Lisa;Hellsinki;;
05;Loris;Sicilia;;
05;Vera;Sicilia;;31
```